# How to scale cubes to fit array to create radial tile system

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to create a radial tile system where the outer rims have more bricks than the inner ones. That far I've managed to get, but how do I scale them to fit the length of the array. I've tried scaling by index, by position and tried to use Accumulate field, but my noob brain isn't enough. Help please! :) [image][image]

Comment: Do you want to achieve rounded briks, or should the bricks themselves stay straight?
Depending on that, there are several options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to generate the circles you showed like this:

[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly! I really need to study your solution, to understand Geometry Nodes a bit better

Answer (score -1):

Here's a hacky and easy to understand way to do it. but you need to make sure the resample curve must be a multiple of the integer node.
[image]

Comment: The image with nodes is too small to be able to distinguish anything.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer, i was on vacation. Your solution looks interesting, but what are you using as the input geometry though?

Comment: no worries,I'm using a mesh circle.